# Difference between Windows 8 Apps &Windows Store apps?

Tags: windows-8

Can anyone tell me the difference between Windows 8 Apps & Windows Store Apps.And also What kind of permissions does a developer need from Microsoft ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a notion like "Windows 8 Apps". Standard apps are no different from Windows 7 apps, Windows Vista apps etc.. But there are new kind of application called "Windows Metro Apps", "Windows Store Apps" etc.(I don't know the official name). Those apps are distributed via Windows Store only and they are quite different from any older application windows users used to.

To write one you need to use WinRT API which replaces many old WinAPI functions. Mainly those which works with an outer world(especially I/O). To make sure you don't use anything forbidden(aka old API) you need to pass certification. You can read more about certification and constraints [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx).
Also you need to be registered developer to upload any application to the Store. It costs 19$ and you get developer license for Windows Store and Windows Phone Marketplace, afaik.